# ValueError at /store/place_order/ Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: user>>": "Order.user" must be a "User" instance

Tags: python, django

I am very new with django, i am trying to build a e-commerce store in django
in my django project i have two applications accounts and store
i my accounts application my form.py looks like this:-

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms

class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    mobile_number = forms.CharField(max_length=15, required=True)
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'), ('O', 'Other')], required=True)

    class Meta():
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'date_of_birth', 'gender', 'mobile_number', 'password1', 'password2',)
    model = get_user_model()
    
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].label = 'Display Name'
        self.fields['email'].label = 'Email Address'
        self.fields['mobile_number'].label = 'Mobile Number'
        self.fields['date_of_birth'].label = 'Date of Birth'
        self.fields['gender'].label = 'Gender'
```

in accounts/views.py:-

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from . import forms
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .forms import UserCreateForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django.views.generic import TemplateView




class SignUp(CreateView):
    form_class = forms.UserCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
    template_name = 'accounts/signup.html'




def profile(request):

    return render(request,'accounts/profile.html',{'username':request.user, 'email':request.user.email, 'first_name':request.user.first_name, 'last_name':request.user.last_name})






class UserCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
    template_name = 'accounts/signup.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        self.success_url = reverse_lazy('profile', args=[self.object.pk])
        return response
```

in my store application
models.py looks like this: -

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from accounts.models import User
import uuid




class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.name} - {self.product.name}"
```

in my store app store/views.py: -

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import OrderForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model  
from .models import Order


User = get_user_model()

def index(request):
    return render(request,'index.html')

class ThanksPage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'thanks.html'

from .models import Product
from .forms import OrderForm

def product_list(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'store/product_list.html', {'products': products})

@login_required
def place_order(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save(commit=False)
            order.user = request.user  
            order.save()
            return redirect('order_confirmation', order_id=order.id)  
    else:
        form = OrderForm()
    return render(request, 'store/place_order.html', {'form': form})

def order_confirmation(request, order_id):
    order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=order_id)
    return render(request, 'store/order_confirmation.html', {'order': order})
```

in my store store/forms.py:-

```
from django import forms
from .models import Order
from .models import Product

class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['product', 'quantity']
        exclude = ['user']


class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

I tried using `order.user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)` but no luck.